# AnimationDrawable in ImageView stop working in API 22 and 23

Tags: android, android-animation

I have in my app a GridView with ImageViews which have animations(animation-list from xml file) set to background and foreground(drawable) - different to each. I use this code to start animations:

```
((AnimationDrawable)unitsGrid.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.img).getBackground().stop();
((AnimationDrawable)((ImageView)unitsGrid.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.img)
.getBackground()).getDrawable().stop();
((AnimationDrawable)unitsGrid.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.img).getBackground().start();
((AnimationDrawable)((ImageView)unitsGrid.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.img)
.getBackground()).getDrawable().start();
```

It's working like I want in my real device(4.4.2) and in AVD emulator in APIs 15-21(I don't test in lower). When I run it on API 22 or 23 in AVD it's only animate background, foreground(drawable) is not animating(it's in first frame like in begin) but application works normally. Animation's duration is above 1 second so it couldn't be lag.

Google change something in API 22 and don't support Image foreground animations anymore, it's bugged on that APIs or it's only emulator bug?

Someone know something about it?

Thanks in advance.